# How to pronounce - Fragen

Tags: discussion

Da sich diese Art der Frage gerade häuft und in den Kommentaren bereits angedeutet wird, dass sie kein guter Fit für diesen SE-Bereich sind, wollte ich dies mal allgemein zur Diskussion stellen.

So wird zum Beispiel gesagt

> [These questions] are all the equivalent of translation requests, just for pronunciation.

Translation requests sind allerdings gar nicht off-topic. Es sollte nur nicht in *bulk* sein und ein "allgemeines Interesse" bestehen. Bei den Namen von Wissenschaftlern würde ich ein allgemeines Interesse sehen.

> I don't think this type of question is a good fit for the site, as the answer wouldn't even have to be a sentence, just a transcription [fʁ...]. There is no problem to be solved, nothing to be explained.

Ich würde die Qualität einer Frage nicht notwendigerweise an der Länge ihrer Antwort messen. Ich bin mir außerdem sicher, dass sich auch längere Antworten finden würden.

Solche Fragen sind auch in der Vergangenheit aufgetaucht:

[Phonetic help for 'Frobenius'](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6717/phonetic-help-for-frobenius)

[Pronunciation of “Leonhard Euler”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28862/pronunciation-of-leonhard-euler)

[Pronunciation of "Dirichlet"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48498/pronunciation-of-dirichlet)

Ich würde vorschlagen einen Sammelthread "Pronounciation of Scientists" zu erstellen, in denen wir die Aussprache auflisten. Das bringt ein bisschen mehr Ordnung in das Ganze Und wir haben nicht 20 Threads mit 20 Einzeilerantworten.
Oder das ganze gleich auszuweiten und "Pronounciation of Public Characters" draus zu machen.

Comment: Danke, dass du das Thema hier aufgreifst! - Meta ist der bessere Ort für diese Diskussion als in den Kommentaren der jeweiligen Fragen. Welche Vorteile hat ein Sammelthread? Ich sehe dadurch eigentlich eher mehr Unordnung als Ordnung :) Vielleicht wäre ein Tag sinnvoll?

Comment: Nach Kategorien gelistet (Wissenschaftler, Schauspieler, Sänger, etc.) und alphabetisch sortiert sehe ich darin keine Unordnung :) Den Vorteil daran sehe ich darin, dass eben alles an einem Ort ist.

Comment: Ich versuche, mir plastisch vorzustellen, wie das aussehen würde. Ich habe ein paar offene Fragen: Woher wissen wir, was gute Kategoriengrenzen sind? Wie sollen die Antworten aussehen? Als Community-Answer? Ich sehe da vor allem Probleme. "Alles an einem Ort" hätten wir im Grunde auch mit einem Tag.

Comment: Ich habe mal zwei Vorschläge angefügt, bitte diskutieren und bearbeiten :)

Comment: Ich sehe keinen Sinn darin, zu versuchen, ein phonetisches Namenswörterbuch aufzubauen. Wozu soll das gut sein, gerade bei ganz gewöhnlichen deutschen Namen, an deren Aussprache nun wirklich nichts besonderes ist? Bei außergewöhnlichen Namen ist das etwas anderes. Ob man eine Tag benötigt, ist eine sekundäre Erwägung. Prinzipiell soll es mir egal sein, mich hat die Häufung dieser banalen Fragen halt etwas genervt.

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass man eine solche Namensliste der Aussprachen nach Kategorien der Leute sortiereren muss oder sollte. Eine alphabetische Suche danach wäre vollkommen ausreichend ohne dass man ausführen muss in welchen Bereichen eine Person herausragendes geleistet hat.

Comment: @planetmaker: ... zumal man den Architekten Wagner, den Komponisten Wagner und den Exfußballer Wagner - sie alle gleich ausspricht, unabhängig von ihrer Profession.

Comment: @userunknown was bei Namen nicht notwendigerweise der Fall sein muss

Comment: @infinitezero: Beispiel?

Answer (score 4):

Ein Tag wäre die bessere Lösung.

[public-characters](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-characters)
*For questions concerning names of public characters*

Comment: Was denkst du über `name-pronunciation`? Ich denke etwa auch an die Aussprache von Ortsnamen.

Comment: Ich habe gerade gemerkt, der Tag [tag:person-names] existiert bereits. (https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/person-names)

Answer (score 2):

Vorausschicken möchte ich, daß ich @infinitezero's Idee mit dem Tag für eine gute Idee halte, allerdings für einen allgemeineren Namen als "public-figures" bin. Eher schon "pronounciation", falls es den noch nicht gibt. Wie @JonathanScholbach in einem Kommentar angemerkt hat, gilt dasselbe ja auch für etwa Ortsnamen - und vermutlich andere Begriffe.

Der Grund, warum eine Liste, in welcher Form auch immer, problematisch werden könnte, ist die Auswahl, was in diese Liste kommen soll: wir hatten in der Diskussion schon "Berühmte Persönlichkeiten" und dann kam die Ergänzung "Ja, aber Ortsnamen vielleicht auch". Ich garantiere, als nächstes haben wir dann die Diskussion, was genau "berühmt" konstituiert<sup>1</sup>) und ob eine bestimmte Person in die Liste kommen soll oder nicht. Daran anschließend kommt die Diskussion, was genau eine "Person"<sup>2</sup>) ist, etc., ad nauseam. Diese Diskussion(en) kann man sich sparen, denn sie führen zu absolut nichts, außer vielleicht Edit-Wars á la Wikipedia.

Eingehen möchte ich noch auf @DavidVogt's Einwände, weil sie mir über den unmittelbaren Anlaß hinaus wesentlich erscheinen:

> Die Antwort ist vorhersagbar

Sprache ist ein Verständigungsmittel und deshalb intrinsisch darauf angelegt, von allen Emittenden/Rezipienten gleichartig aufgefaßt zu werden. Das nennt man "Verständnis". Schon möglich, daß das nicht immer zutrifft (Mißverständnisse kommen vor), aber wären diese der Allgemeinfall, dann würde Sprache ihre Funktion nicht mehr erfüllen. Schon aus dem Grund sind Fragen zur Sprache (mit wenigen Ausnahmen) immer "vorhersagbar" - schon deshalb, weil ein sehr weitreichendes Einverständnis über die Bedeutung unter den Sprechern einer Sprache existieren muß, damit diese überhaupt als "Sprache" fungieren kann.

Die allermeisten Antworten sind "vorhersagbar", wenn man sich erst die Sprachkompetenz eines Muttersprachlers erwirbt, dann den Duden und ein paar andere einschlägige Werke auswendig lernt und in Sachen Morphologie, Semantik, Semiotik, Germanistik und ein paar anderen Wissenschaften auf dem allerneuesten Stand der Forschung ist. Wenn wir Fragen nicht zuließen, weil sie von diese Voraussetzungen erfüllenden Personen sowieso gleichartig (also "vorhersagbar") beantwortet würden, dann müßte man 95% (oder eher mehr) von German-SE einstampfen. Das allerdings ist für die meisten zu viel verlangt, insbesondere für jene überwiegende Mehrheit der Menschen, die eben *keine* Muttersprachler sind (und selbst für die meisten, die es sehr wohl sind).

Man kann das Pferd aber auch von der anderen Seite her aufzäumen:

#### Was wollen wir hier eigentlich?

Was wir als akzeptable Fragen definieren hängt doch im Wesentlichen davon ab, was wir auf bzw. mit dieser Seite eigentlich erreichen wollen. Mir ist schon klar, daß es dafür gewisse Rahmenbedingungen gibt, die Stackexchange insgesamt, die Moderatorenschaft, etc., vorgeben. Innerhalb dieser "von außen" gesetzten Grenzen gibt es jedoch Spielraum für Interpretation und diesen sollte jeder nutzen um diese grundlegende Frage für sich zu beantworten. Die Frage, ob nach der korrekten Aussprache eines Namens, Orts (oder, allgemein, eines Begriffs) gefragt werden können soll, ist nur ein Detail in diesem Antwortprozeß.

---

<sup>1</sup>) Beispiele gefällig: "Georg Cantor" wird vermutlich nicht bezweifelt werden, auch, wenn sein Name außerhalb von Mathematikerkreisen kaum bekannt ist. Wie sieht es aus mit "[Michael Aschbacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Aschbacher)"? Den kennt nun, außer Mathematikern die Gruppentheorie betreiben, niemand.

<sup>2</sup>) Auch hier ein Beispiel aus der Mathematik: ist "[Nicolas Bourbaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki)" eine "Person"?

Answer (score 0):

Ich halte diese Art von Frage aus zwei Gründen für unangemessen:

1. Die Antwort besteht aus einer einzelnen Transkription; es gibt kein zugrundeliegendes Problem, das erörtert werden könnte. Den Aspekt, daß es um ein **Problem** gehen soll, empfinde ich als Wesensmerkmal der Seite: es geht nicht um "die richtige Antwort", sondern um den Weg, wie man zu dieser gelangt; um die relevanten Konzepte, die man hinzuziehen muß; um die unterschiedlichen Antworten, zu denen man gelangen kann.
2. Die Antwort ist **vorhersagbar**, indem die Aussprache in der Regel der allgemeinen Laut-Buchstaben-Zuordnung folgt. (Sollte sie dies nicht tun – *Soest, Mecklenburg* – ist die Frage selbstverständlich zulässig.)

Parallele Begründungen dienen dazu, Fragen auszuschließen, die durch ein Wörterbuch oder eine Deklinationstabelle beantwortet werden können: auch in diesem Fall geht es nicht um ein Problem und die Antwort ist vorhersagbar.

Wäre diese Art von Frage zulässig, könnten ab sofort beliebig viele Fragen der Form *Wie spricht man den Namen … auf Deutsch aus* generiert werden. Das empfinde ich als nicht wünschenswert. Sie sollten also geschlossen werden.

Comment: Gibt es denn brauchbare Wöterbücher mit Phonetikumschreibung (IPA) oder Audioschnipsel online? Ein Blick zu dict.leo.org zeigt mir keine Hilfe, im Duden finde ich für "EUler" die Betonung dargestellt und zum ähnlichen Wort "Eule" auch eine Hörprobe. Ich hatte jetzt nicht die Muße ein representatives Sample auszuprobieren.

Comment: Mein Punkt war: Man muß die Aussprache in der Regel nicht nachschlagen, man kann einfach ablesen. Wenn einem auffällt, daß man nicht weiß, wie <eu> oder unbetontes <er> gesprochen werden, kann man nachschlagen: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussprache_der_deutschen_Sprache. Wenn das nicht reicht, gibt es Seiten wie https://forvo.com/. Das wären die Schritte, die meinem Empfinden nach einer Frage vorangehen sollten.

Comment: Jetzt ist es mir klarer.

Answer (score -2):

Angelehnt an den Thread [Resources for Learning German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german) würde ich das ganze als Communitywiki aufziehen und einzelne Antworten pro Kategorie hinzufügen, sodass diese direkt verlinkt werden können.

Einzelne Einträge hätten dann die Form:

> Euler, Leonhard: /ˈleːonhaʁt ˈɔɪ̯lɐ/

Comment: Ich denke, das ist eine machbare Lösung. Ich sehe nur ein Problem, wenn es mal Dissens zu einzelnen Namen gibt. Auch "einzelne Antworten pro Kategorie" ist ein : Was ist, wenn sich die Kategoriengrenzen verschieben? Was ist, wenn eine Person in mehrere Kategorien fällt? Nur ein Beispiel: Ist Martin Sonneborn ein Comedian oder ein Politiker? Kategorisierung ist typischerweise schwer...

Comment: Dann vielleicht die Kategorien doch sein lassen und nur alphabetisch?

Comment: Ja, das wäre einfacher, denke ich :) Aber die Abwägung hängt auch davon ab, welchen Nutzen wir darin sehen, dass alles in einem Thread ist. Kannst du sagen, was du an einem einzelnen Thread besser findest als an einem Tag?

Comment: Ein klarer Vorteil wären weniger Klicks und weniger suchen. Wenn ich die Aussprache von 3 Mathematikern suche, müsste ich nur entsprechend die eine (lange) Liste abscrollen oder ggf. mit `ctrl+f` hinspringen. Das ist ein Klick auf den Thread und dann nur noch scrollen bzw etwas tippen. Im anderen Falle müsste auf den Tag klicken und dort dann schauen, ob ich die anderen Mathematiker finde, da die Fragen/Antworten anzeige meines Wissens nach nicht sinnvoll sortiert ist (und selbst wenn, müssten alle Fragen dann auch noch eindeutig benannt sein). Und dann dort den Thread wieder anklicken....

Comment: Oder ich müsste jedes mal einen neuen Namen eintippen und den Thread suchen (granted, das wäre wie wenn ich mit ctrl+f suche), aber wenigstens muss ich dann nicht klicken :)

Comment: Ich sehe bei solchen Listen den Nachteil, dass Benutzer die einen Namen suchen, der noch nicht auf der Liste ist, keinen guten bzw. offensichtlichen Platz haben, um nach Erweiterungen der Liste zu fragen. SE bietet keine guten Funktionen, um solche Listen zu verwalten.

Comment: @Hulk die Kommentar Funktion eigenet sich bestens dazu

Comment: @infinitezero: Leider eben nicht, weil nach einer bestimmten Anzahl Kommentareen nur noch "x more comments" angezeigt wird. Mit <CTRL>-f im Browser zu suchen wird dann nix.

Comment: @bakunin Kommentar Posten, Name wird hinzugefügt, Kommentar wird gelöscht